# Change position of array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let cards = [
   { name: 'a', value: '234'},
   { name: 'b', value: '876' },
   { name: 'c', value: '765'},
   { name: 'd', value: '980' }
];
let defaultCard = 'c';
```

I want to the defaultCard to be the first card in `cards` array.
In this case result will be

```
cards = [
   { name: 'c', value: '765'},
   { name: 'a', value: '234'},
   { name: 'b', value: '876' },
   { name: 'd', value: '980' }
]
```

What is the best possible way.

What I have done is to get index of default card and swap with the 0 index.

```
function getIndex(arr, defaultCard) {
  return arr.findIndex((item) => item.name === defaultCard);
}
function getSortedCard(arr) {
  let index = getIndex(arr, defaultCard);
  if (index < 1) return arr;
  let temp = arr[index];
  arr[index] = arr[0];
  arr[0] = temp;
  return arr;
}

const newArr = getSortedCard(cards);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Please show us your efforts, then if there are any issues we can help

Comment: @ASDFGerte , Please check my code. I have edited. If you can suggest something.

Comment: There is a very adequate answer by now, so i do not think i have to. However, i removed my downvote, as the edited question includes proof of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the original array, you can find the index (`Array.findIndex()`), and then construct a new array by putting the element at the index at the top, and spreading the slices that come before and after the index:

```js
const moveToTop = (name, arr) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.name === name);
  
  if(idx === -1) return arr;
  
  return [
    arr[idx],
    ...arr.slice(0, idx),
    ...arr.slice(idx + 1)
  ]
}

const cards = [{"name":"a","value":"234"},{"name":"b","value":"876"},{"name":"c","value":"765"},{"name":"d","value":"980"}];
const defaultCard = 'c';

const result = moveToTop(defaultCard, cards);

console.log(result);
```

If you want to mutate the array, use `Array.splice()` to remove the item, and use `Array.unshift()` to insert it at the top:

```js
const moveToTop = (name, arr) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.name === name);
  
  if(idx === -1) return arr;
  
  arr.unshift(...arr.splice(idx, 1));
  
  return arr;
}

const cards = [{"name":"a","value":"234"},{"name":"b","value":"876"},{"name":"c","value":"765"},{"name":"d","value":"980"}];
const defaultCard = 'c';

const result = moveToTop(defaultCard, cards);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it via destructuring and `Array.filter` method.

```js
let cards = [
   { name: 'a', value: '234'},
   { name: 'b', value: '876' },
   { name: 'c', value: '765'},
   { name: 'd', value: '980' }
];
let defaultCard = 'c';

cards = [cards.find(item => item.name === defaultCard), ...cards.filter(item => item.name !== defaultCard)];

console.log(cards);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.sort()`method and have the match sort higher:

```js
let cards = [{
    name: 'a',
    value: '234'
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    value: '876'
  },
  {
    name: 'c',
    value: '765'
  },
  {
    name: 'd',
    value: '980'
  }
];
let defaultCard = 'c';

let ans = cards.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name === defaultCard) {
    return -1
  }
  return 1
})

console.log(ans)
```

Comment: @ASDFGerte apologies for offending you. What makes the compare function improper?

Comment: It returns `1` for any call where the default element is not the first parameter, making it not symmetrical, to name just one point. For the result, you scramble the other elements, apart from moving the default to the front.

Comment: Ah i see, the issue is, that this "by chance" gives the desired result on chrome. This is really just "by chance", to make things clear. Firefox for example already won't give the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, if i am a bit overly disgruntled, i guess that's my day's fault, not yours. Lets clear things: 1) a sort has O(n log(n)) time complexity, while this problem should be solved in linear time. 2) a comparefunction passed to `sort` has to meet certain criteria ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) - scroll down a bit, the "A function comparefn is a consistent [...]" part), or the resulting order is implementation defined. In your case, chrome's V8 "happens to give the desired result", but this is just luck, other implementations don't (e.g. FF).